# ha-jdbc dependency for maven 2

Tags: maven-2, pom.xml

could someone please post me the maven 2 dependency for ha-jdbc and if there is any need to add extra repository?

Answer (score 1):

The Laughingpanda repository seems to have it: http://www.laughingpanda.org/maven2/ha-jdbc/ha-jdbc/

You'll need to add that repository to your pom, too, something like this:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>laughingpanda</id>
        <name>Laughing Panda</name>
        <url>http://www.laughingpanda.org/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Btw, http://mavensearch.net/ is usually a good point for searching maven artifacts (excluding this one however .. )

> Blockquote

Comment: hi @mglauche, i actually noticed later, that the repository does not contain the latest version, rather a very old version. i am still looking for the right one. please let me know if you found it.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should have a maven repository of yours which queries other repositories when it doesn't have a specific library. In that repository you can manually add libraries which are not available through any other maven repository. That is what we are planning to do with ha-jdbc. BTW did your experiment with ha-jdbc go well?